# Getting DHCP hostname

Tags: debian, dhcp

I am currently setting up Debian Wheezy on a system and network autoconfigure fails and asked to retry with a DHCP hostname.

I have another system (also running Debian Wheezy) hooked up to the same switch. I'd like to use that system to find out what its DHCP hostname is so that I can supply that to the other system.

I've tried searching around by so far I have been unable to find out how to do it.

Comment: What DHCP server are you running?  With most setups you shouldn't need a DHCP hostname.

Comment: Oops there my problem. As far as I can tell I'm not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to find the DHCP server, run in the other machine.

```
grep dhcp-server-identifier /var/lib/dhcp/dhcp*leases
```